# Flat attribute : example I don't understand

Tags: core-language, attributes

I am just beginning to learn about attributes of function in mathematica.

I saw the example "Flat". But there is something I don't get :

```
SetAttributes[fonction, Flat]

fonction[fonction[x]]

(*fonction[x]*)

fonction[x_] := x^2;

fonction[fonction[x]]

(*$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of fonction[x].

Hold[fonction[fonction[x]]]*)
```

Why do I have an error ? Shouldn't it returns me fonction[x]=x^2 because of the flat attribute ?

Comment: Look at the result from just `fonction[x]`, you likely want to add the Attribute [`OneIdentity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity.html).

Answer (score 8):

To understand what has happened, let's just define:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {Flat}];
f[x_] := Hold[x];
f[1]
(*Returns Hold[f[1]]*)
```

The reason for this extra `f` in the output is that for a `Flat` symbol expressions `f[x]` and `f[f[x]]` are identical. So, when a pattern-matcher encounters `f[1]` it treats the expression as `f[f[1]]` and consequently substitutes `f[1]`, not `1`, instead of `x` in the *rhs* of the definition. The pattern matcher prefers `f[f[1]]` over `f[1]` when matching `x_` to allow for matching a sequence of arguments as a whole:

```
f[1, 2]
(*Returns Hold[f[1, 2]]*)
```

Here the pattern matcher treated `f[1, 2]` as `f[f[1, 2]]` and replaced `x` by `f[1, 2]` accordingly.

As chuy has already mentioned in the comments, you can add `OneIdentity` attribute to a symbol. Then the pattern-mathcer will prefer `f[1]` over `f[f[1]]` when matching `f[x_]` if there is only one argument inside the expression:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
f[x_] := Hold[x];
f[1]
f[1, 2]
(*Returns Hold[1] and Hold[f[1, 2]]*)
```

Note, however, that `OneIdentity` attribute will not save your form recursion when there are more than one argument: `f[1, 2]` will be matched as `f[f[1, 2]]`, `f[1, 2]` will be squared, `f[1, 2]^2`, and the `f[1, 2]` inside the square will again be matched as `f[f[1, 2]]`. So, basically, use `Flat` attribute only for symbols which really stand for some associative operators or you are likely to get into trouble.

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
f[x_] := x^2;
f[1]
f[1, 2]
(*1
  $RecursionLimit::reclim2 bla-bla-bla
  Hold[f[1, 2]^2]
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

The following example may help:

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
Hold[f[f[x]]] /. HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2
```

The result is:

```
Hold[f[f[x]]^2]
```

To see what's happening, we may run

```
MatchQ[f[a, b], f[_]]
```

The result is True. Thus we see that f[a,b] is identified as f[f[a,b]]. This is what the attribute Flat does to a function.